# Looking for a multi-platform charting lib (Android & iOS)

Tags: android, ios, charts

For our app we are looking to add a flexible and good-looking charting library.
Must haves:

- Zooming
- Auto axis
- Line and Bar charts
- Same look for iOS and Android

Are there any recommendations? It doesn't have to be a freeware thing...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To address multi-platform, I think I would go with a web-based chart such as highcharts and display as in-app webview

Comment: If you are looking for interactive charts which are not in webview, look at shinobi charts. ITs paid though and i am a user.

Comment: subrahmanyam boyapati answer is good to go with if u need assistance anywhere you can inbox me anytime regarding that library and you can draw any chart using this in android and iOS

Answer (score 2):

Below are libraries to draw chart

iOS library:
https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Android Library:
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: Xcode 14 is not supported in iOS.